# Does there exist a linear map with a non-singletone kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone show an example of a *linear* map, kernel of which contains not only zero?

Because I saw a theorem that says kernel of a linear map is a subspace of its domain but I can't imagine how for example taking $u$ and $v$ from its kernel (of course, if there any map with non-singleton kernel) and adding them will still result in an element which is in the kernel. That is why I am looking for such a kernel.

P.S. I am looking for non-trivial example. Is there any? Or it is just limited to zero map?

Comment: That' simply because if $f(u)=0$  and $f(v)=0$, then $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$ (by linearity) $=0+0=0$.

Comment: Map the entire vector space into the zero vector. Now the kernel is the entire vector space.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I am looking for a non-trivial example

Comment: @Bernard thank you, Bernard. I am looking for an example not why it works. My imagination is not sufficient, so I can't accept the theorem completely unless I know some examples where this theorem is a life-saver. Otherwise it is like a useless theorem.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov Consider the orthogonal projection in the real plane onto a line through the origin. The kernel will be the entire line through the origin orthogonal to the other but it is not trivial since the image is a different one dimensional subspace.

Comment: As a geometric example, consider for instance,  in 3-space,  the orthogonal projection of a vector onto a plane through the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by $f(x,y) = (x+y,2x+2y)$.

Its kernel consists of all vectors of the form $(t,-t)$.

Comment: This is more complex that it really needs to be, but I wanted to avoid possible cases of "but that's trivial because ..."